# What kind of module is this?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, modules, local-rings, localization

Recall that, if $R$ is a commutative ring, then a suitably finite $R$-module $M$ is projective if and only if the localization $M_\mathfrak{m}$ is a direct sum of finitely many copies of $R_\mathfrak{m}$ for every maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}\subseteq R$.

Consider the following alternate condition for an $R$-module $M$: each $M_\mathfrak{m}$ is a direct sum of finitely many copies of $R_\mathfrak{m}$ and finitely many copies of $\mathfrak{m}$.

Does this type of module have a global characterization or a name?

Comment: Such a module could be quite bad if $R$ is nonreduced, e.g., a local Artinian ring.  If the scheme is a nodal curve, such modules come up as limits of locally free modules in the Altman-Kleiman compactification of the moduli space of vector bundles.  If $R$ is $S2$, then the reflexive hull of such a module is locally free, and the cokernel is a direct sume of (reduced) skyscraper sheaves / modules.

Comment: @Jason Thanks for this very interesting comment! In the example I have in mind, the ring is, in fact, reduced. Can something more be said under this assumption?